# вход discord по selenium

Tags: python, selenium

ребят помогите пожалуйста.хочу автоматизировать вход в дискорд при помощи selenium
пять часов пытался при помощи разных элементов и исходного кота страницы сделать автоматизацию искал в интернете ничего не нашел поэтому обращаюсь к вам с просьбой о помощи.если не сложно помогите пожалуйста (ниже часть только с номером)

````
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#url = "https://discord.com/login"
import unittest
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
   executable_path="/home/paramonov/Рабочий стол/1/ddd/geckodriver")
try:
   driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)
   driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
   search_box = driver.find_element("css selector", "input-2g-os5")

   search_box.send_keys("99999999999")
except Exception as ex:
   print(ex)
finally:
   time.sleep(3000)
   driver.close()
   driver.quit() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, тебе нужно авторизоваться в дискорде с помощью селениума, для этого советую использовать токен.

Для этого тебе нужно авторизоваться в дискорд желательно через браузер, далее открыть код элемента и перейти во вкладку **Application**. Слева выбрать **Local Storage**. Найти ключ token (не tokens) и скопировать или сохранить его куда-то.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем для авторизации с помощью селениума можно использовать следующий код

```
def auth(token: str) -> None:
    """Auth in discord via token"""
    url_login = 'https://discord.com/login'
    driver.get(url_login)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script(
        f"setImmediate(() => document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe')).contentWindow.localStorage.token = '\"{token}\"');"
        )
     driver.refresh()
```